# Closures in ordered squares

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the following closures of the following subsets of the $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ are true:

(a) $B=\left\{(1-\frac{1}{n})\times \frac{1}{2}|\ n \in Z_{+})\right\}$ has $Cl(B)= B\cup \left\{1\times 0\right\}$

(b) $C=\left\{x\times 0\ |\ 0<x<1\right\}$ has $Cl(C)= C\cup [0,1)\times 1$

(c) $D = \left\{x\times \frac{1}{2}\ |\ 0<x<1\right\}$ has $Cl(D) = D\cup (0,1]\times 0\cup [0,1)\times 1$

(d) $E = \left\{\frac{1}{2}\times y\ |\ 0<y<1\right\}$ has $Cl(E) = E\cup \left\{\frac{1}{2}\times 0, \frac{1}{2}\times 1\right\}$

I have thought of the proof for a while, but I couldn't get how we can obtain the extra points in those closure formulas above. Can someone please help me with this part?

Comment: I suggest you define what the ordered square is. I'm pretty sure I know what you mean, but I've never heard this name for it before.

Comment: Edited now! Hopefully you can give it a try:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has the lexicographic order topology and that $x\times y$ is your notation for the ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$, then (a), (c), and (d) are correct. However, (b) is not quite right: you need to add the point $1\times 0$ to what you already have.

**Added:** I’ll use $\prec$ and $\preceq$ for the lexicographic order. To see why $1\times 0\in\operatorname{cl}B$, let $U$ be an open nbhd of $1\times 0$. Then there are $x_0\times y_0$ and $x_1\times y_1$ such that $1\times 0\in(x_0\times y_0,x_1\times y_1)\subseteq U$. There’s nothing ‘below’ $1\times 0$ on the line $x=1$, so the only way to have $x_0\times y_0\prec 1\times 0$ is to have $x_0<1$: if $x_0$ were $1$, we’d have $x_0\times y_0=1\times 0$ if $y_0=0$, and $1\times 0\prec x_0\times y_0$ if $y_0>0$, so no matter what $y_0$ is, we’d have $1\times 0\preceq x_0\times y_0$ instead of $x_0\times y_0\prec 1\times 0$. Now choose $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ large enough so that $x_0<1-\frac1n$; then $x_0\times y_0\prec\left(1-\frac1n\right)\times\frac12\prec 1\times 0$, so

$$\left(1-\frac1n\right)\times\frac12\in U\cap B\;.$$

$U$ was an arbitrary open nbhd of $1\times 0$, so we’ve shown that every open nbhd of $1\times 0$ contains a point of $B$ and hence that $1\times 0\in\operatorname{cl}B$.

The arguments for the extra points in (b) are similar to those for (c), so I’ll skip them. In (c) consider the point $p=x\times 0$, where $0<x\le 1$. If $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$, there must be an $x_0<x$ and a $y_0>0$ such that $p\in(x_0\times 1,x\times y_0)\subseteq U$.

> You may have to think about this a little: you know that there must be some open interval $(q,r)\subseteq U$ such that $q\prec p\prec r$, and with a bit of thought you should be able to convince yourself that we can always shrink the interval $(q,r)$ if necessary so that $r$ lies ‘above’ $p$, and $q$ is at the ‘top’ of its vertical segment, i.e., has second coordinate $1$.

Now choose any $x_1$ such that $x_0<x_1<x$; then $x_1\times\frac12\in U\cap D$. Thus, every open nbhd of $p$ contains points of $D$, and $p\in\operatorname{cl}D$. The argument that $p=x\times 1\in\operatorname{cl}D$ whenever $0\le x<1$ is similar, except that you work to the right of $p$ instead of to the left.

Finally, (d) is the easiest, since the set $E$ is just the vertical open interval between $\frac12\times 0$ and $\frac12\times 1$. Any open interval containing $\frac12\times 0$ must ‘reach up’ into this interval, and any open interval containing $\frac12\times 1$ must ‘reach down’ into it, so both endpoints of the interval must be in its closure.

In each part of the problem you should also try to see why no *other* points are in the closure of the given set: around each point not in the closure you should be able to find an open interval disjoint from the given set.

Comment: M.Scott: you're right, I fixed the typo for $E$. However, I had trouble proving that the extra points is actually in each closure above. Can you please explain why those are the cases? And may you elaborate on the point $1\times 0$ for $C$ (i.e, why this point is in Cl(C))?

Comment: @user177196: I’ve added considerable explanation; see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Any open set of the lexicographic order that contains $1\times 0$ is an open 'interval' of the form:
$U: = (a,1) \times [0,1] \cup \{a\} \times (b,1] \cup \{1\} \times [0,c)$ where $a < 1$ and $b,c \in [0,1]$.
Thus  $U \cap C \not= \emptyset.$

Comment: how did you get that formula for $U$? You are explaining why $1\times 0$ is in Cl(C)?

Comment: By definition of the lexicographic order, if $V$ is any open set that contains $1$ x $0$, then it must contain an open interval $U$. As this interval $U$ has end points strictly smaller and strictly larger than $1$ x $0$, it must be of the form $a$ x $b$, where $a < 1$ and $b \in [0,1].$ Similarly there must be a point $m$ x $n$ that is larger than $1$x$0$, so by definition $m =1$ and $c: = n > 0$. Try drawing the interval in the ordered square, then write it as a union of cartesian products.